# Ubuntu not booting after cloning (OSX and Kali)

Tags: unix, dual-boot, grub

the task was too simple - I had a 256gb ssd with OSX (apfs) and Kali (osx booted with Alt pressing and Kali booting on default - I suspect GRUB was operating). I think there was a problem after upgrading to ubuntu 16 so rEFInd menu just disappeared.

I bought a new 512GB ssd and tried to clone OSX partition - it was fine but i had to tackle problem with containers, recovery hd, hidden partition and so on.

Now OSX is booting and I successfully cloned ext4 partition (Kali) with GParted and installed rEFInd via recovery hd. Now rEFInd is working but there's no option for my Kali partition.

I understand there should be a shortcut with bootloader\grub conf without Kali reinstall Kali and cloning partition once again (if ever it boots).

How do I make this ext4 partition boot (supposing cloning was successful)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

OK, after searching for 2 days I finally got the answer.

So I had a bootable apfs OSX partition with rEFInd installed from OSX. rEFIND couldn't find ext4 partition from OSX natively. That was the problem. ext4 partition was cloned from source later on.

1. Download Kali live-USB, mount it using dd or rufus or any other software.
2. Reboot, Hold `alt` to boot from Kali USB, then follow the instructons from here https://medium.freecodecamp.org/kali-installation-on-usb-stick-with-pure-efi-boot-on-a-mac-37585b7698e2 section "Boot from Live GRUB".
3. After you log in (**here's the main trick**): download a debian version of rEFInd (.deb)
   and install it:

`sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE`

4. Reboot. Your Kali partition should appear on rEFInd boot menu together with OSX.